# How to convert this XML into kotlin array

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, unicode, hex

I need help if there is any expert in XML and kotlin. I would like to know how to convert the  below XML access it in kotlin code and then convert it into kotlin array  file i.e. like (USD -> $) so  the value of USD is the  symbol which   the  unicode of  from the XML.

I know in Android there is java utill class  but the problem  there is  there  is not all currencies symbols available i.e. for AFN -> there is AFN but  in actual it  should be -> ؋.

here is XML file:

```
<currency-symbol count="115">
  <entry code="ALL" unicode-decimal="76, 101, 107" unicode-hex="4c, 65, 6b">Albania Lek</entry>
  <entry code="AFN" unicode-decimal="1547" unicode-hex="60b">Afghanistan Afghani</entry>
  <entry code="ARS" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Argentina Peso</entry>
  <entry code="AWG" unicode-decimal="402" unicode-hex="192">Aruba Guilder</entry>
  <entry code="AUD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Australia Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="AZN" unicode-decimal="1084, 1072, 1085" unicode-hex="43c, 430, 43d">Azerbaijan New Manat</entry>
  <entry code="BSD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Bahamas Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="BBD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Barbados Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="BYR" unicode-decimal="112, 46" unicode-hex="70, 2e">Belarus Ruble</entry>
  <entry code="BZD" unicode-decimal="66, 90, 36" unicode-hex="42, 5a, 24">Belize Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="BMD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Bermuda Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="BOB" unicode-decimal="36, 98" unicode-hex="24, 62">Bolivia Boliviano</entry>
  <entry code="BAM" unicode-decimal="75, 77" unicode-hex="4b, 4d">Bosnia and Herzegovina Convertible Marka</entry>
  <entry code="BWP" unicode-decimal="80" unicode-hex="50">Botswana Pula</entry>
  <entry code="BGN" unicode-decimal="1083, 1074" unicode-hex="43b, 432">Bulgaria Lev</entry>
  <entry code="BRL" unicode-decimal="82, 36" unicode-hex="52, 24">Brazil Real</entry>
  <entry code="BND" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Brunei Darussalam Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="KHR" unicode-decimal="6107" unicode-hex="17db">Cambodia Riel</entry>
  <entry code="CAD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Canada Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="KYD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Cayman Islands Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="CLP" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Chile Peso</entry>
  <entry code="CNY" unicode-decimal="165" unicode-hex="a5">China Yuan Renminbi</entry>
  <entry code="COP" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Colombia Peso</entry>
  <entry code="CRC" unicode-decimal="8353" unicode-hex="20a1">Costa Rica Colon</entry>
  <entry code="HRK" unicode-decimal="107, 110" unicode-hex="6b, 6e">Croatia Kuna</entry>
  <entry code="CUP" unicode-decimal="8369" unicode-hex="20b1">Cuba Peso</entry>
  <entry code="CZK" unicode-decimal="75, 269" unicode-hex="4b, 10d">Czech Republic Koruna</entry>
  <entry code="DKK" unicode-decimal="107, 114" unicode-hex="6b, 72">Denmark Krone</entry>
  <entry code="DOP" unicode-decimal="82, 68, 36" unicode-hex="52, 44, 24">Dominican Republic Peso</entry>
  <entry code="XCD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">East Caribbean Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="EGP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Egypt Pound</entry>
  <entry code="SVC" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">El Salvador Colon</entry>
  <entry code="EEK" unicode-decimal="107, 114" unicode-hex="6b, 72">Estonia Kroon</entry>
  <entry code="EUR" unicode-decimal="8364" unicode-hex="20ac">Euro Member Countries</entry>
  <entry code="FKP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Falkland Islands (Malvinas) Pound</entry>
  <entry code="FJD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Fiji Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="GHC" unicode-decimal="162" unicode-hex="a2">Ghana Cedis</entry>
  <entry code="GIP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Gibraltar Pound</entry>
  <entry code="GTQ" unicode-decimal="81" unicode-hex="51">Guatemala Quetzal</entry>
  <entry code="GGP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Guernsey Pound</entry>
  <entry code="GYD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Guyana Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="HNL" unicode-decimal="76" unicode-hex="4c">Honduras Lempira</entry>
  <entry code="HKD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Hong Kong Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="HUF" unicode-decimal="70, 116" unicode-hex="46, 74">Hungary Forint</entry>
  <entry code="ISK" unicode-decimal="107, 114" unicode-hex="6b, 72">Iceland Krona</entry>
  <entry code="INR" unicode-decimal="" unicode-hex="">India Rupee</entry>
  <entry code="IDR" unicode-decimal="82, 112" unicode-hex="52, 70">Indonesia Rupiah</entry>
  <entry code="IRR" unicode-decimal="65020" unicode-hex="fdfc">Iran Rial</entry>
  <entry code="IMP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Isle of Man Pound</entry>
  <entry code="ILS" unicode-decimal="8362" unicode-hex="20aa">Israel Shekel</entry>
  <entry code="JMD" unicode-decimal="74, 36" unicode-hex="4a, 24">Jamaica Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="JPY" unicode-decimal="165" unicode-hex="a5">Japan Yen</entry>
  <entry code="JEP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Jersey Pound</entry>
  <entry code="KZT" unicode-decimal="1083, 1074" unicode-hex="43b, 432">Kazakhstan Tenge</entry>
  <entry code="KPW" unicode-decimal="8361" unicode-hex="20a9">Korea (North) Won</entry>
  <entry code="KRW" unicode-decimal="8361" unicode-hex="20a9">Korea (South) Won</entry>
  <entry code="KGS" unicode-decimal="1083, 1074" unicode-hex="43b, 432">Kyrgyzstan Som</entry>
  <entry code="LAK" unicode-decimal="8365" unicode-hex="20ad">Laos Kip</entry>
  <entry code="LVL" unicode-decimal="76, 115" unicode-hex="4c, 73">Latvia Lat</entry>
  <entry code="LBP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Lebanon Pound</entry>
  <entry code="LRD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Liberia Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="LTL" unicode-decimal="76, 116" unicode-hex="4c, 74">Lithuania Litas</entry>
  <entry code="MKD" unicode-decimal="1076, 1077, 1085" unicode-hex="434, 435, 43d">Macedonia Denar</entry>
  <entry code="MYR" unicode-decimal="82, 77" unicode-hex="52, 4d">Malaysia Ringgit</entry>
  <entry code="MUR" unicode-decimal="8360" unicode-hex="20a8">Mauritius Rupee</entry>
  <entry code="MXN" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Mexico Peso</entry>
  <entry code="MNT" unicode-decimal="8366" unicode-hex="20ae">Mongolia Tughrik</entry>
  <entry code="MZN" unicode-decimal="77, 84" unicode-hex="4d, 54">Mozambique Metical</entry>
  <entry code="NAD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Namibia Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="NPR" unicode-decimal="8360" unicode-hex="20a8">Nepal Rupee</entry>
  <entry code="ANG" unicode-decimal="402" unicode-hex="192">Netherlands Antilles Guilder</entry>
  <entry code="NZD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">New Zealand Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="NIO" unicode-decimal="67, 36" unicode-hex="43, 24">Nicaragua Cordoba</entry>
  <entry code="NGN" unicode-decimal="8358" unicode-hex="20a6">Nigeria Naira</entry>
  <entry code="KPW" unicode-decimal="8361" unicode-hex="20a9">Korea (North) Won</entry>
  <entry code="NOK" unicode-decimal="107, 114" unicode-hex="6b, 72">Norway Krone</entry>
  <entry code="OMR" unicode-decimal="65020" unicode-hex="fdfc">Oman Rial</entry>
  <entry code="PKR" unicode-decimal="8360" unicode-hex="20a8">Pakistan Rupee</entry>
  <entry code="PAB" unicode-decimal="66, 47, 46" unicode-hex="42, 2f, 2e">Panama Balboa</entry>
  <entry code="PYG" unicode-decimal="71, 115" unicode-hex="47, 73">Paraguay Guarani</entry>
  <entry code="PEN" unicode-decimal="83, 47, 46" unicode-hex="53, 2f, 2e">Peru Nuevo Sol</entry>
  <entry code="PHP" unicode-decimal="8369" unicode-hex="20b1">Philippines Peso</entry>
  <entry code="PLN" unicode-decimal="122, 322" unicode-hex="7a, 142">Poland Zloty</entry>
  <entry code="QAR" unicode-decimal="65020" unicode-hex="fdfc">Qatar Riyal</entry>
  <entry code="RON" unicode-decimal="108, 101, 105" unicode-hex="6c, 65, 69">Romania New Leu</entry>
  <entry code="RUB" unicode-decimal="1088, 1091, 1073" unicode-hex="440, 443, 431">Russia Ruble</entry>
  <entry code="SHP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Saint Helena Pound</entry>
  <entry code="SAR" unicode-decimal="65020" unicode-hex="fdfc">Saudi Arabia Riyal</entry>
  <entry code="RSD" unicode-decimal="1044, 1080, 1085, 46" unicode-hex="414, 438, 43d, 2e">Serbia Dinar</entry>
  <entry code="SCR" unicode-decimal="8360" unicode-hex="20a8">Seychelles Rupee</entry>
  <entry code="SGD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Singapore Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="SBD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Solomon Islands Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="SOS" unicode-decimal="83" unicode-hex="53">Somalia Shilling</entry>
  <entry code="ZAR" unicode-decimal="82" unicode-hex="52">South Africa Rand</entry>
  <entry code="KRW" unicode-decimal="8361" unicode-hex="20a9">Korea (South) Won</entry>
  <entry code="LKR" unicode-decimal="8360" unicode-hex="20a8">Sri Lanka Rupee</entry>
  <entry code="SEK" unicode-decimal="107, 114" unicode-hex="6b, 72">Sweden Krona</entry>
  <entry code="CHF" unicode-decimal="67, 72, 70" unicode-hex="43, 48, 46">Switzerland Franc</entry>
  <entry code="SRD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Suriname Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="SYP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">Syria Pound</entry>
  <entry code="TWD" unicode-decimal="78, 84, 36" unicode-hex="4e, 54, 24">Taiwan New Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="THB" unicode-decimal="3647" unicode-hex="e3f">Thailand Baht</entry>
  <entry code="TTD" unicode-decimal="84, 84, 36" unicode-hex="54, 54, 24">Trinidad and Tobago Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="TRY" unicode-decimal="" unicode-hex="">Turkey Lira</entry>
  <entry code="TRL" unicode-decimal="8356" unicode-hex="20a4">Turkey Lira</entry>
  <entry code="TVD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Tuvalu Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="UAH" unicode-decimal="8372" unicode-hex="20b4">Ukraine Hryvna</entry>
  <entry code="GBP" unicode-decimal="163" unicode-hex="a3">United Kingdom Pound</entry>
  <entry code="USD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">United States Dollar</entry>
  <entry code="UYU" unicode-decimal="36, 85" unicode-hex="24, 55">Uruguay Peso</entry>
  <entry code="UZS" unicode-decimal="1083, 1074" unicode-hex="43b, 432">Uzbekistan Som</entry>
  <entry code="VEF" unicode-decimal="66, 115" unicode-hex="42, 73">Venezuela Bolivar</entry>
  <entry code="VND" unicode-decimal="8363" unicode-hex="20ab">Viet Nam Dong</entry>
  <entry code="YER" unicode-decimal="65020" unicode-hex="fdfc">Yemen Rial</entry>
  <entry code="ZWD" unicode-decimal="90, 36" unicode-hex="5a, 24">Zimbabwe Dollar</entry>
</currency-symbol>
```

the resulting array should be I believe a 2D array I just need the iso code i.e. USD and symbol which would be $ for USD so two values I need (USD, $).

the array should be something like this:

```
 val currencies = resources.getStringArray(R.array.currencies)
        val USD_SYMBOL = ""
        run lit@{
            for (curr in currencies) {
                for (c in curr) {
                    if (c[0] == USD) {
                        USD_SYMBOL = c[1]
                        return lite@
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, the resulting array should be I believe a 2D array I just need the iso code i.e. USD and symbol which would be  $ for USD so two values I need (USD, $). tnx

Comment: I just added at the last of question body please see it there. tnx

Comment: please see how I want the resulting array to use in my code. the question is  on both sides the  how to make XML to work on the above scenario  as  well as how  to manage  that by kotlin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242652/discussion-between-mohammad-khalid-shehab-and-fureeish).

Comment: What about `INR` which has no information on currency symbol in your XML?

Comment: INR is not needed as  per the requirements.

Comment: This is not valid XML: the declaration is missing.

Comment: how  to fix  this  any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val xml = """
  <currency-symbol count="115">
    <entry code="ALL" unicode-decimal="76, 101, 107" unicode-hex="4c, 65, 6b">Albania Lek</entry>
    <entry code="AFN" unicode-decimal="1547" unicode-hex="60b">Afghanistan Afghani</entry>
    <entry code="ARS" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Argentina Peso</entry>
    <entry code="AWG" unicode-decimal="402" unicode-hex="192">Aruba Guilder</entry>
    <entry code="AUD" unicode-decimal="36" unicode-hex="24">Australia Dollar</entry>
    <entry code="AZN" unicode-decimal="1084, 1072, 1085" unicode-hex="43c, 430, 43d">Azerbaijan New Manat</entry>
  </currency-symbol>
"""

data class Currency(
  val code: String,
  val name: String,
  val symbol: String
)

val currencies = xml.trimIndent()
  .substringAfter(">").substringBeforeLast("</")
  .split("\n")
  .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
  .map {
    val splitted = it
      .split("(<entry code=\")|(\" unicode-decimal=\")|(\" unicode-hex=\")|(\">)|(</entry>)".toRegex())
      .filter { s -> s.isNotBlank() }
    Currency(
      code = splitted.first(),
      name = splitted.last(),
      symbol = (splitted.drop(1).dropLast(1).lastOrNull() ?: "")
        .split(",")
        .filter { s -> s.isNotBlank() }
        .map { s -> Integer.parseInt(s.trim(), 16).toChar() }
        .joinToString("")
    )
  }

currencies.forEach { println(it) }
```

Output:

```
Currency(code=ALL, name=Albania Lek, symbol=Lek)
Currency(code=AFN, name=Afghanistan Afghani, symbol=؋)
Currency(code=ARS, name=Argentina Peso, symbol=$)
Currency(code=AWG, name=Aruba Guilder, symbol=ƒ)
Currency(code=AUD, name=Australia Dollar, symbol=$)
Currency(code=AZN, name=Azerbaijan New Manat, symbol=ман)
```

Comment: Thank you! it is just the thing that I want I implemented the code in my android kotlin project and created a function now takes currency code as a parameter and returns the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you have the unicode values of currency symbols (which are sometimes multi-character ones).

In addition, I used [simple-xml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.simpleframework/simple-xml) because I don't want to deal with regexes to parse XMLs, especially since this library is [quite easy to use](https://medium.com/codechai/how-to-parse-xml-using-kotlin-in-2021-21f2fffbdf22).

Fully working code:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.*
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister
import java.io.File

@Root(strict = false, name = "entry")
class Entry {
    @field:Attribute(name = "code", required = true)
    var code: String? = null

    @field:Attribute(name = "unicode-decimal", required = false)
    var unicodeDecimal: String? = null
}

@Root(strict = false, name = "currency-symbol")
class CurrencySymbols {
    @field:ElementList(name = "entry", inline = true, required = false)
    lateinit var entries: ArrayList<Entry>
}

fun main() {
    val filePath = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Downloads\\currency-symbols.xml"

    val fileContent = File(filePath).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

    val serializer = Persister()
    val data = serializer.read(CurrencySymbols::class.java, fileContent)

    val symbolMappings = data.entries
        .map { it.code to it.unicodeDecimal.toUnicodeSymbol() }
        .associateBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
    
    println(symbolMappings["PLN"])
    println(symbolMappings["EUR"])
    println(symbolMappings["AFN"])
    println(symbolMappings["INR"])
    println(symbolMappings["USD"])
}

private fun String?.toUnicodeSymbol(): String =
    if (this.isNullOrEmpty()) ""
    else this.split(",")
        .map(String::trim)
        .map { Character.toChars(it.toInt()) }
        .joinToString(separator = "") { it.joinToString("") }
```

First I created the `Entry` and `CurrencySymbols` classes. They are *mappings* of your `<entry>` and `<currency-symbol>` tags.

Then I read the whole file to a single `String` (`fileContent`) and, using `simpleframework`'s `Persister` I created a `CurrencySymbols` object called `data`.

Every single `Entry` was then `map`ped to a pair of a currency code and its symbol. Notice that a symbol can be empty, can be a single unicode code-point or can consist of multiple code-points (as it is with `PLN` which maps to `zł`). `associateBy` takes care of turning that list of pairs into a map, which enables the nifty `[]` syntax to grab the symbol of the desired currency.

`String?.toUnicodeSymbol()` was a fun function to write - it takes a (possibly `null`) list of code-points, for example `76, 101, 107` and turns them into a single `String` containing unicode characters obtained from those codepoints.

Comment: Thank you! Fureeish ! I really appreciate your time and solution